# How to use EncloseJS

Tags: javascript, enclose

i have script test.js with content

`console.log('Hello, this is EncloseJS test.');`

Later will be in this file some function or other important code.

I compile it with enclose js like `enclose test.js -o test.bin`

Now, i need exec it in my javascript application. 
I tried something like `require('test.bin')` or `eval('test.bin');` but i think, it is not right way.

Can someone hel me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this way:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var cmd = 'path/to/test.bin';

exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr)
```

Never tried it , but do give me a feedback

Comment: Ok, test.bin was executed, but output is in stdout variable as string. But i need in test.js define custom function and then execute binary version test.bin and than run function defined in test.bin. I need to protect this function.

Comment: @martinsojak, basically you want to make it private, right?

Comment: Yes, i want to make it privat and use function from test.bin in other javascript codes. Something like `<script src="test.js"></script> there is `function testFunction(){ //do something}` function in test.js ... and later use function testFunction(); in other code.